# Order of fields in scattering amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, conventions, scattering, feynman-diagrams

Given the lagrangian
$$\mathcal L=-\dfrac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+(D_{\mu}\phi)^*(D^{\mu}\phi)-M^2|\phi|^2+\bar\psi(i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}-m)\psi.$$
I tried to compute some first order scattering amplitudes for different scattering processes and I noticed that sometimes I write the fields associated to the particles in the scattering in a different way respect to the solutions.
I thought that, given a channel ($s$, $t$ or $u$), the order of the fields in the expression of $i\mathcal M_{s,t,u}$ was always the same, so I was wondering if there are particular rules that I don't know.

For example, suppose we have the above Lagrangian, what's the expression of the scattering amplitude for $$f(p_1)+s(p_2) \to f(p_3)+s(p_4)~?$$
here I denoted with s a complex scalar field $\phi$ and with $f$ a Dirac field.

Comment: Hi @Alchemist and welcome to PSE. Perhaps consider writing what $f$ and $s$ stand for... Maybe it is not obvious for everyone